# How can I scroll to an element so that it's at the bottom of the scrolling div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to automatically scroll to an element but I can't get it to scroll so that #elem is at the bottom of the #crm_corp_scroll div. I tried using

```
$j('#crm_corp_scroll').animate({scrollTop: $j('#'+elem).offset().top},'fast');
```

but it scrolls the div so that the element is at the top and out of view.

I tried the native scrollIntoView but it scrolls me to the middle of the element. I want the full element to be into view.

[jsFiddle for how it works right now](http://jsfiddle.net/HLxGM/). I want it to scroll so row6 is at the bottom of #crm_corp_scroll.

Figured out a sollution:

```
$j('#crm_corp_scroll').animate({scrollTop: ($j('#'+elem).offset().top - $j('#crm_corp_scroll').height() + $j('#'+elem).height() * 2) },'fast');
```

this scroll elem into view at the bottom of the #crm_corp_scroll div.

Comment: Do you have an example website or a jsFiddle?

Comment: $j('#'+elem).offset().top + $j('#'+elem).height()

Comment: I'll work on a jsFiddle for it. Also, @TrinhHoangNhu that scrolls me to below the target element.

Comment: Yeah just create a jsfiddle and we'll see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Tried different approach which can fit your needs better:

http://jsfiddle.net/HLxGM/5/

---

I changed your jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HLxGM/2/)

See if it works as intended.

I took the row.offset().top - box.height() + (row.height() * 2) and it seems to work as intended.

A more reliable solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HLxGM/3/)

Take the row.offset().top - box.offset().top - box.height() + (row.height() * 2) and it also works when it's on other places then the start of a document.

Comment: That scrolls to just below the element. I want it to scroll so that the #elem is at the bottom of #crm_corp_scroll.

Comment: I'm sorry, I realized some of the wording I used is a bit misleading. As I said, I want to have row6 at the bottom of #crm_corp_scroll

Comment: Yeah that's what I wanted, the only problem now is that if the row is higher than one row of text, it still doesn't scroll all the way down so all of the target row is visible